`divide` function in TikZ?
This TeX code runs without any errors. A line is drawn from the point (0, 0) to the point (3, 0), and the characters A, B, and C are placed on the points (1, 0), (2, 0), and (3, 0) respectively along the line. Could someone explain what divide is, and how it can be used in this context?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (3, 0) 
      node[pos = divide 1 3] {A}
      node[pos = divide 2 3] {B}
      node[pos = divide 3 3] {C};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

